# how to prevent a condition when setInterval is running

Tags: javascript

I've watched many tutorials with alarm clocks and created my own but I'm still learning JS and I can't pause the sound because setInterval in the clock is running. pause() doesn't work because in a second the alarm is still going off. Can anyone help me?

```js
let now;
let hours;
let minutes;
let seconds;

function clock() {
  now = new Date();
  hours = now.getHours();
  minutes = now.getMinutes();
  seconds = now.getSeconds();

  // add zero for the values lower than 10
  if (hours < 10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  document.querySelector(".hours").innerHTML = hours;
  document.querySelector(".minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.querySelector(".seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
  console.log(`${hours}:${minutes}`);

  // ##### this is the part sounds the alarm #####

  if (alarmTime == `${hours}:${minutes}`) {
    console.log(`Alarm ringing...`);
    ringtone.play();
    ringtone.loop = true;
  }
}
let updateClock = setInterval(clock, 1000);

let alarmTime;

let ringtone;
ringtone = new Audio("./files/alarm.wav");

function setAlarm() {
  let time = `${selectMenu[0].value}:${selectMenu[1].value}`;
  alarmTime = time;
  content.classList.add("disable");
  setAlarmBtn.innerText = "alarm is set";
  console.log(alarmTime);
}
setAlarmBtn.addEventListener("click", setAlarm);

// ##### This is one of some attempts to stop it
function stop() {
  ringtone.pause();
  ringtone.loop = false;
}
```

```html
<button class="alarm-clock-button">set alarm</button>
<button class="alarm-off-button" onclick="stop()">alarm off</button>
```

I don't want to copy the whole code because it is quite bulky.

Comment: I didn't use it because I want the clock to run but I want to switch the alarm off. I have a clock + the alarm clock. If I clearInterval, the clock will stop working.

Comment: When you want to stop it, you can use the clear interval after the stop button is clicked and it will stop it from ringing.

Comment: change `alarmTime` so it doesn't re-trigger

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable the setInterval entirely, use `clearInterval(updateClock)`, if you don't want to disable it then you can put a boolean variable `isPaused` and check for it when `alarmTime` is being checked, you can use `isPaused = !isPaused` in your stop function to toggle it or just use `false`

Code Example:

```js
let isPaused = false; //declaration

if (alarmTime == `${hours}:${minutes}` && !isPaused) { // this will replace the condition!
    console.log(`Alarm ringing...`);
    ringtone.play();
    ringtone.loop = true;
}

function setAlarm() {
  let time = `${selectMenu[0].value}:${selectMenu[1].value}`;
  alarmTime = time;
  content.classList.add("disable");
  setAlarmBtn.innerText = "alarm is set";
  console.log(alarmTime);
  isPaused = false; // If it's being reset for whatever reason
}

function stop() { // this will replace your stop function
  ringtone.pause();
  ringtone.loop = false;
  isPaused = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example with some code?

Comment: @TerminalDiscord, how to use "isPaused = true"in this code?

Comment: I could also refresh the page which could remove the event listener an would stop the function from running. I can't use your solution.